# Turn off search privacy

Tags: php, search-engine, profile

How can I hide the profile details from search engines using php?

I want to prevent the search engines from user`s details in my website only when the user

set turn off search privacy from their account page.

Ex: Facebook profile privacy

Answer (score 0):

You can add following lines to your header part of your html/php page

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a robots.txt with something like the following

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /profile
```

More information on possible options can be found [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may try using [`/robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) but there's no guarantee that they will really respect that configuration.

The second thing you may do is to just hide contains from robots by specifying blacklist (you can [google `list of search robot ip`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=list%20of%20search%20robots%20ip)) all ips from lists like [this one](http://www.iplists.com/) (although this is practice which is [used by malware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546330/1149736)).

Answer (score 0):

Using robots.txt / html meta tags is nice if the bot respects them but is otherwise pointless. The only ready way to protect the info is to use some sort of authentication system where only registered members may view certain content otherwise limiting who can see what.